# Are these two subrepresentations mutually complement both algebraically and topologically?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, representation-theory

Consider a topological group $G$, a topological vector space $\mathbb W$, and the space $\mathbb V$ of continuous functions:
$$
{\mathbb{V}} = \left\{\varphi~\,{\Large{|}}\,~\varphi\,:~G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{W}}\right\}~.
$$
A representation $\;A:\,G\longrightarrow GL(\mathbb{V})\;$ implies:
$$
A:\qquad G\times {\mathbb V} \longrightarrow {\mathbb V}\;,\quad (g,\,v)\longmapsto A_g\,v
$$
and is acting by left translations:
$$
A(G):\;\;\varphi(g^{\prime})\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}\varphi(g^{-1}g^{\prime})\;,\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
$$
where $g^{\prime}$ is a free variable.

We may consider functions $\varphi(k')$ defined on a topological subgroup $K<G$ as functions which are defined on $G$ but are set to be zero on elements outside of $K$. Such functions constitute a topological vector subspace $\,{\mathbb V}_1\subset\mathbb V$.

The restriction of representation $A$ to the subspace $\,{\mathbb V}_1\,$ is a subrepresentation of $A(G)\,$:
$$
A_1(G):\; \varphi(k)\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}\varphi(g^{-1}k)\;.\;\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$

The functions on $G$ which are zero on $K$ constitute a subspace $\,{\mathbb V}_2\subset\mathbb V$, and we may denote the corresponding restriction of $A(G)$ as $A_2(G)$.

QUESTION 1.

Are the spaces $\,{\mathbb V}_1$ and $\,{\mathbb V}_2$ one another's complements both algebraically *and topologically*?

QUESTION 2.

Are the subreps $A_1(G)$ and $A_2(G)$ complementary both algebraically *and topologically*?
Stated alternatively, are both $\,{\mathbb V}_1$ and $\,{\mathbb V}_2$ closed?

Comment: A subspace $W\subset V$ gives a subrepresentation only if $\forall g\in G, g W = W$

Comment: @reuns Do you imply that in my case both spaces ${\mathbb{V}}_1$ and ${\mathbb V}_2$ are closed? How to prove this?